# Adding click events to user control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a user control in an asp.net web application. The control outputs an html list that is customized based on the currently logged in user.  The list items are generated from a database look up and the user control is formatted to appear as a drop down list in the page.

The control itself is simple and looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="item-lector.ascx.vb" Inherits="includes_usercontrols_item_selector" %>
<!--Item Selector-->
<div id="item-selector">
<%=Me.Output%>
</div>
```

The code behind file dynamically fills the control's "output" property so the final markup appears as follows:

```
<div id="item-selector">
<h1>Item 1 - Item 1</h1>  
<a href="#" class="changeItem  itemArrow">Change item</a>  
<ul id="changeItemMenu" class="dropDownMenu">    
<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>    
</ul>
</div>
```

The ID and class properties are all necessary for formatting and other scripting.  The control is meant to be used as a selector and the rest of the page should react to which item the user selects.

What I am trying to do is add click events to the list items.  When the user clicks on one of the items in the list, I want to capture which item the user selects in the list (does this require a postback?) and **do something with it in the code behind** (< this is key).

I am more of a middle tier and db tier developer and UI development is not my strength so please consider me a newbie in that regard. I am not sure how to proceed or what to inject into the output string to enable this.  Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to postback to server to capture which item the user selected, you need only Javascript code on client side.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="item-lector.ascx.vb" Inherits="includes_usercontrols_item_selector" %> 
<!--Item Selector--> 
<div id="item-selector"> 
<%=Me.Output%> 
</div> 
<!-- add this code here after the </div> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   function createFunc(i){ return function(){ alert("You clicked element " + (i + 1) + " in the list"); return false; } }   
   var els = document.getElementById('changeItemMenu').getElementsByTagName('a'); 
   for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) 
      els[i].onclick = createFunc(i); 
</script>
```

In this code we add events applying directly the `onclick` attribute, a better way to add event would be to use a [function like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631241/simple-javascript-to-mimic-jquery-behaviour-of-using-this-in-events-handlers) or an entire library like jQuery or YUI or whatever you like.

Comment: Hi Marco, thank you for quick your response.  When I add the code you supplied, the alert says that I clicked element #23 in the list, no matter which element I click on.  How can I get access to that particular element server-side in the code behind?

Comment: @MHV88: well I updated the code and now it works. This is only client side, I did not understand from your question, you had to do it server side. Sorry I don't know ASP cause I use PHP, so I can not be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

You may not necessarily need to use postbacks,
but if you want to, you need to use something called `delegates`.
check it out over here: [link](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html)

Even if you don't use them,  they are useful, and will allow you to add "custom" events to your user control.

---

**Edit:**
Here is some code you can use:
First you define your delegate type. Think of a delegate like a function pointer.
You will definte this in your code-behind:

```
public delegate void OnChangeDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Then you will define the actual event to be of type `OnChangeDelegate` type.

```
public event OnChangeDelegate Change;
```

Then you create a method (or two) which "fires" your event:
*(this is in your ascx.cs file)*

```
public void ItemChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null && sender is LinkButton)
    {
        string idx = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;
        FireMyChangeEvent(sender, idx);
}
```

Also

```
private void FireMyChangeEvent(object sender, string index)
{
    if (MyItemChange != null)
    {
        EventArgs e = new EventArgs();

        Change(sender, new ItemSelectorEventArgs(index));
    }
}
```

So anywhere in your codebehind, you can pass a handle to the control and some extra stuff in the EventArgs object.

Now the tricky part is getting your `<li>` s to cause a postback.
Traditionally, you would use a `<select>` and `<option>`s because of the native `onclick` event, but since you are rendering a `<ul>` and `<li>`s 
You might want to wrap them with an `<asp:LinkButton runat="server">` so you get an event firing, instead of the `<a href="#">`, so you can say `OnClick` for that LinkButton, and in that event, you can just call your `ItemChange` method to fire your control's event, and pass the id of the item which you can send in the EventArgs of your event.

I would definitely recommend reading the link I sent you, and remember that unless a control has `runat="server"` your server will not have any handle on it.

**Update*: Here is some more code.

**MY ASPX Code**
Note here that `WebUserControl1` is my user control and `MyClick` is the method defined in ASPX.cs code.

```
<ul>
    <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" OnChange="MyClick"/>
</ul>
```

**My ASCX Code**
Note here that the CommandArgument is used to specify which item is clicked. Also, you can use this for a database id or some such value, I just use a simple integer ordinal.

```
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server" OnClick="ItemChange" CommandArgument="1">item1</asp:LinkButton></li>
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="lb2" runat="server" OnClick="ItemChange" CommandArgument="2">item2</asp:LinkButton></li>
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="lb3" runat="server" OnClick="ItemChange" CommandArgument="3">item3</asp:LinkButton></li>
```

**In APX.CS Code**
Note here that `lblResult` is a simple

```
<asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" />
```

I used this just for display purposes

```
protected void MyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int myitem = ((WebUserControl1.ItemSelectorEventArgs)e).ItemSelected;

    lblResult.Text = "You clicked Item " + myitem.ToString() + "!";
}
```

**Lastly**

This is the Custom Event Args class I created in my `ascx.cs` code:

```
public class ItemSelectorEventArgs : EventArgs
{

    public int ItemSelected
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ItemSelectorEventArgs(string indexSelected)
    {
        int tryGetANumber;

        if (int.TryParse(indexSelected, out tryGetANumber))
        {
            this.ItemSelected = tryGetANumber;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ItemSelected = -1;
        }

    }
}
```

**Remember**
You are trapping the events of the HTML Controls inside your user control, gathering some info from them, and firing a custom event on your user control.

Comment: Hi funkymushroom, thank you for your response.  Can you provide some more detail specific to my example?

Comment: I am following what you say right up until the end.  I replaced the <a href> tag with a link button and added an onclick=ItemChange(). What parameters do I add to that method?  Also, I am a confused by what you wrote onchange="mychangeeventmethod" where does that go and how is it used?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have added some more code and modified this with more details.